# How to find counting inversion using mergesort in Python?

Tags: python, mergesort

This is my program for finding counting inversion in mergesort algorithm, though I'm not able to find the correct inversion value. Can anybody please tell me where am I going wrong?

```
import time
import random
start=time.time()

def merge_sort(items):
    """ Implementation of mergesort """
    count=0
    if len(items) > 1:

        mid = len(items) // 2        # Determine the midpoint and split
        left = items[0:mid]
        right = items[mid:]

        merge_sort(left)            # Sort left list in-place
        merge_sort(right)           # Sort right list in-place

        l, r = 0, 0
        for i in range(len(items)):     # Merging the left and right list

            lval = left[l] if l < len(left) else None
            rval = right[r] if r < len(right) else None

            if (lval is not None and rval is not None and lval < rval) or rval is None:
                items[i] = lval
                l += 1
            elif (lval is not None and rval is not None and lval >= rval) or lval is None:
                items[i] = rval
                count=count+(len(items)-l)
                r += 1

        print(count)        
    return items

#n=int(input("enter number of elements in list"))
items=[2,1,5,4,3,9]
#for x in range (n):

 #   items.append(random.random())


print(merge_sort(items))
print("time is %s"%(time.time()-start))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to calculate the number of inversions in a list of numbers.

```
def count_inversions(items):
    inversions = 0
    for idx, item in enumerate(items):
        if idx < len(items) - 1 and items[idx] > items[idx + 1]:
            inversions += 1
    return inversions
```

You need to call this once. It goes above any recursive calls (left and right).